# cassandra cluster not re-starting upon improper shutdown

Tags: cassandra, shutdown, recovery, power-off

I have a test cluster on 3 machines where 2 are seeds all centos7 and all cassandra 3.4. 
Yesterday all was fine they were chating and i had the "brilliant" idea to ....power all those machines off to simulate a power failure.
As a newbie that i am, i simply powered the machines back and i expected probably some kind of supermagic, but here it is my cluster is not up again, each individual refuses to connect.
And yes, my firewalld is disabled.

My question : what damage was made and how can i recover the cluster to the previous running state?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you abruptly shutdown your cluster, that simply means, nodes were not able to drain themselves.

Don't worry, it is unlikely any data loss happened because of this, as cassandra maintains commit logs, and will read from it when it is restarted.

First, find your seed node ip from `cassandra.yaml`
Start your seed node first.

Check the start up logs in `cassandra.log` and `system.log` and wait for it to start up completely, it will take sometime.
As it will read from commit log for pending actions, and will replay them.

Once it finishes starting up, start other nodes, and tail their log files.

Comment: True, thank you. So seeds nodes first and rest after. No need to repair anything on the node, they should serve the coffee where they left it away.

Comment: Ideally you shouldn't need too. You will find out soon enough from logs, if any data corruption happened.

Comment: Checked the logs, all fine. Off-topic : for the moment my firewalld is down. i should let all the ports 7000,7001,7199,9042,9160 opened? or for my local internode comm just the 7000? 9042 i am sure listens for remote connections, 9160 i know is the thrift one, dunno about others.

Comment: I don't recall what ports are used for gossip protocol for communication of data between inter-nodes. I'll suggest allow all communication based on ip 's for node ip. Also, please select this as answer, this will help others who arrive here eventually.

Comment: **7000** ( if TLS is not enabled ) must be added in firewall/iptables so the nodes can communicate. If you have only one interface add it in public zone ( firewalld ). If you have 2 and one is dedicated locally set it in the internal zone. LIke that the nodes should communicate just fine.